# How do I pass/save and push the input data to a web service in ionic 2/angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms, typescript2.0, angular2-databinding

I am trying to create a comment form with ratings. In this form , i have added the way for users to rate the app and comment aswell. I am pretty new to angular 2 and kind of struggling how I can save this user entered data and/or push it to a custom web service, to retrieve it next time i open the form. Here's the code so far:
comment-star.html:

```
<ion-header class="top-header">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title class="my-title">
      {{title}}
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="dismiss('')">
      <span showWhen="ios">x</span>
      <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding no-bounce>
  <ion-label class="label">How would you rate our app?</ion-label>
 <ion-grid no-padding no-margin class="ion-rating-container">
    <ion-row>

<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" 
        value="5" 
        [name]="inpustName"
        [checked]="rating===5" />
    <label title="Excellent!" (click)='onClick(5)'>5 stars</label>

    <input type="radio" 
        value="4" 
        [name]="inpustName"
        [checked]="rating===4" />
    <label title="Pretty good" (click)='onClick(4)'>4 stars</label>

    <input type="radio" 
        value="3" 
        [name]="inpustName"
        [checked]="rating===3" />
    <label title="Satisfactory" (click)='onClick(3)'>3 stars</label>

    <input type="radio" 
        value="2" 
        [name]="inpustName"
        [checked]="rating===2" />
    <label title="Not good" (click)='onClick(2)'>2 stars</label>

    <input type="radio" 
        value="1" 
        [name]="inpustName"
        [checked]="rating===1" />
    <label title="Terrible" (click)='onClick(1)'>1 star</label>
</fieldset>

</ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-label class="label">Tell us how we can improve our app?</ion-label>

  <ion-textarea no-bounce class="text-area" rows="11" placeholder="Add a review"></ion-textarea>
  <button ion-button class="button-text"round (click)="dismiss('')">Submit</button> 


</ion-content>
```

comment-star.scss:

```
comment-star {
    .button-text {
        width:40%;  
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-top:5%;
    }
    .text-area{
        margin-left:5%; 
        border:solid 1px black;
        width:90%;
        height:40%;

    }

    button button-ios, button button-md{
        width:40%;  
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-top:5%;

    }

    .label{
        color:black;
        font-size:15px;
        margin-left:5%;
    }
    .inner {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /***************************
    Pulls the stars container to the left
    ***************************/
    .rating {
        float:right;
        overflow:hidden; 
        color:#ddd;
        border-color:white;
        border-width: 0;        
    }

    /***************************
    Hides the radio buttons
    ***************************/
    .rating:not(:checked) > input {
        position:absolute;
        top:-9999px;
        clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
    }
    /***************************
    Default stars styles
    ***************************/
    .rating:not(:checked) > label {
        float:right;
        width:1em;
        padding:1em;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-size:180%;
        line-height:1.3;
        color:#ddd;
    }
    /***************************
    Adds the star symbol to the labels
    ***************************/
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
        content: '★  ';

    }
    /***************************
    Colour for the applied rating stars
    ***************************/
    .rating > input:checked ~ label {
        color: #f70;
    }
    /***************************
    Colour for hovered stars when increasing the rating
    ***************************/
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
        color: gold;
    }
    /***************************
    Colour for hovered stars when decreasing the rating
    ***************************/
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
    .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
        color: #ea0;
    }


}
```

comment-star.ts

```
import { NavController, ViewController,NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
/*
  Generated class for the CommentStar page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'comment-star',
  templateUrl: 'comment-star.html',
})
export class Commentstar{
  title: string = "Rate & Review"

   @Input() rating: number;
    @Input() itemId: number;
    @Output() ratingClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    inpustName:string;

  public firstParam;


  constructor(public nav: NavController,public viewCtrl: ViewController,private app: App,http: Http,public navParams: NavParams) { 
                 this.firstParam = navParams.get("");

  }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.inpustName = this.itemId + '_rating';
    }
    onClick(rating: number): void {
        this.rating = rating;
        this.ratingClick.emit({
            itemId: this.itemId,
            rating: rating
        });
            console.log("rating is:", rating);

    }

  dismiss(item) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item)
  }  
  submit(item){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item)

  } 

}
```

Any tutorials or links to do that will be helpful too.

Comment: Do you have a web service?

Comment: actually, I dont have a webservice for now. However, I am more concerned about saving and retrieving the data locally. How do I do that, so I can send this data via email thru the mailto option in body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question implies you do not have a web service. So my recommendation would be to make a REST Api with .net core and POST and GET request to that api to save and retrieve the data.

To save it locally, in ionic 2, I recommend the Storage plugin shown in the Ionic v2 docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

I created a service, called StorageService where I do all my setting and getting of local data.

**The service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

  public storageKeys: string[] = ['ratings', 'user']

  constructor(public storage: Storage) { }

  // AUTH STORAGE
  public setRatingStorage(rating: any[]) {
    this.storage.set('ratings', {ratings: ratings, time: Date.now()})
      .catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
  }

  public getRatingStorage() {
    return this.storage.get('ratings')
      .catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
  }
  // ...
}
```

**The component/other service injecting StorageService**

```
setRatings(ratings: any[]) {
    // Ratings is an array of ratings that you should push to, then
      // when you want to save/confirm the rating, call this and set
      // the storage. So that you can retrieve it later or in other
      // places throughout the application.
    this._storage.setRatingStorage(ratings);
}

getRatings(): Promise<any> {
   this._storage.getRatingStorage()
       .then(storedRatingData => {
           of(storedRatingData && storedRatingData..length > 0) 
               // Where this.ratings is a local variable that you can manipulate/display
               this.ratings = storedRatingData.ratings;
       }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```